# ¿Vuetify data table con buscador externo?

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, table, vuetify

Tengo el componente v-data-table de vuetify, el cual se le puede agregar una barra de filtrado por defecto en sus propiedades. Esta tabla coge los datos de un json local, hasta aquí todo bien.

El problema viene cuando tengo 1 componente externo a esta tabla, el cual es una barra buscadora creada con(v-form/v-text-field), esa barra deberá de hacer la misma función que la barra buscadora de v-data-table.

¿Como puedo lograr que se comuniquen los componentes entre si y funcione igual que la que trae por defecto v-data-table?

Si necesitan código de ejemplo intentare hacer algún ejemplo resumido.

Answer (score 0):

El componente que viene por defecto dentro de la v-data-table de vuetify que seria este:

```
<template v-slot:top>
    <v-text-field
      v-model="search"
      label="Search (UPPER CASE ONLY)"
      class="mx-4"
    ></v-text-field>
  </template>
```

No controla la búsqueda de la tabla únicamente lo hace la variable :search="search" de v-data-table teniendo esto en cuenta se puede colocar un componente ya sea externo como este:

```
<Busqueda :buscar="search" @update-buscar="buscado"></Busqueda>
```

O cualquier elemento que manipule la variable de búsqueda en este caso "search" adjunto link de como pasar propiedades entre componentes vue

https://codingpotions.com/vue-props